# `glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign` next to TextField

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/aks2oh0d/) the `glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign` is below the `TextField` and I just wonder how is it possible to move the icon on the right side next to the `TextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overview: `</form>` in incorrect location, incorrect parent of form (no need to wrap the form in a ul and then add the same class on both), wrong classes (input-group not form-group) on component. Use data-html="true" if you are using html in your tooltip or popover. Indent and comment your code. Stitch in time saves nine, ya know...

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/licawu/1/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Trdy</a>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-header -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="home-url"><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li id="about-url"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li id="contact-url"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
         <!--/.navbar-nav -->
         <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="get" action="{{ url_for('quick_search')}}" role="form">
            <div class="input-group">
               <input class="form-control" type="text"  name="quick_search" id="quick_search" placeholder="Search" type="submit"> 
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <a href="#" class="my-tool-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" data-html="true" title="Tooltip here <BR> Hello"> 
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
               </a>
               </span>
            </div>
            <!--/.input-group -->
         </form>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
   </div>
   <!--/.container -->
</div>
<!--/.navbar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The text-field div and icon class are currently `block` elements, so they are taking up the full width of their container. So you need to change them to be for example `inline-block` elements:

[Updated code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aks2oh0d/1/)

As you can see I added the below code. This is just one way of doing it:

```
#quick_search {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
}

.input-group-addon {
 display: inline-block;
    width: 9%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but your solution is not not working under Linux (chrome and firefox).

Comment: Hmm interesting.. try using floats instead, here's an updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aks2oh0d/2/

Comment: Still no luck, I removed the button and kept only `glyphicon-info-sign`, but now the tooltip is broken see please updated example  http://jsfiddle.net/ps1ggsc0/2/

Comment: Are you adding in the css I have provided? As the demo you provided their is no css to style the textfield and icon etc?

Comment: In this code http://jsfiddle.net/ps1ggsc0/2/ I haven't used your CSS code, because unfortunately it was not working. Then I removed `"class=input-group-addon"` and `glyphicon-info-sign` moved next the `TextField`, but now the tooltip is broken (please the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/ps1ggsc0/2/).